# Match anything using LIKE in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a search engine and I need to do a query that looks for matching data in four colums from a table with users: name, second_name, lastname and second_lastname, so if I query with something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."' OR last_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."' OR second_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."' OR second_last_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."'
```

Taking a table with a row with this data as example:

```
name: Joe;
lastname:Doe;
second_name:Jordan;
second_lastname: Doeman;
```

A search for Joe, or Doe, or Jordan or Doeman Will get me results from this Joe row, but a search for Joe Doe together is not giving me any result due Joe Doe is not like anything in any of the columns when I hit the first D of Doe, so my question is, is there a way to get this row affected using something like %term% but not from here to here but 'Within' in some way so a term Like Joe Doe still giving me results from the Joe row because of the Joe in Joe Doe. (Joe overdose XDD)

I'm using php and MySQL fyi.

Greetings.

Comment: You want to concat first name and last name then do a wildcard search on that.

Comment: you might find these interesting https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I tried first with MATCH, I set the FULLTEXT in my columns but no result so far, does this looks correct ?

    ("SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE MATCH (name,last_name,second_name,second_last_name) AGAINST ('".$searchTerm."') ORDER BY name ASC");

Comment: So far this two queries are failing :( 

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE MATCH (name,last_name,second_name,second_last_name) AGAINST ('".$searchTerm."') ORDER BY name ASC");

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE concat_ws(' ',name,last_name) '%".$searchTerm."%'");

Comment: Have you tried the query I put in the answer below?

Comment: Yes, but not results at all. I've used CONCAT to get results bind together but not to search for results, I don't know if this is still going to work from a FULLTEXT indexed column because Ive changed them in order to try with the MATCH approach but It didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split up the search string, and use a separate `LIKE` for each word. So if the search string is `Joe Doe`, it should be

```
WHERE name LIKE '%Joe%' OR name LIKE '%Doe%' OR lastname LIKE '%Joe%' OR lastname LIKE '%Doe%' ...
```

You can generate this dynamically like this:

```
$words = explode(' ', $searchTerm);
$tests = array();
foreach($words as $w) {
    $tests[] = "name LIKE '%$w%' OR lastname LIKE '%$w%' OR second_name LIKE '%$w%' OR second_lastname LIKE '%$w%'";
}
$test_string = implode(' OR ', $tests);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE $test_string";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [CONCAT_WS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

So instead of:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."' OR last_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."' OR second_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."' OR second_last_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."'
```

Try:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE concat_ws(' ',first_name,last_name) 
'%".$searchTerm."%';"
```

Comment: His problem is with how he matches the rows, not how he returns the results.